# PHP design- abstract classes and factory methods

Tags: php, oop, class-design, abstract

I am trying to work out the best way to design my classes and I think abstract classes it the right way here, but I'm not sure! I am building a plugin for Wordpress carts that at the moment, will work for both Woocommerce and WP-Ecommerce. As these two systems have different implementations of certain functionality, such as getting an order object, I want to create a separate class for each platform.

I have the following which will contain generic methods that should be available to the classes that inherit from it. This class should never be instantiated:

```
class Order_Export {
}
```

I then have 2 more classes that will inherit from the above:

```
class Order_WooExport extends Order_Export {
}

class Order_WPExport extends Order_Export{
}
```

Is my design right here? Am I right in saying the class Order_Export should be an abstract class? What about methods that I want the class inheriting to implement? Do I simply mark the signature in the abstract class and not provide a body, or do interfaces come into play somewhere here?

How about instantiating the right class? Do I create a factory that will return one or the other?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That sound correct to use abstract base class, as long as you are sure to never need to instantiate `Order_Export` :

```
abstract class Order_Export
{
    abstract protected function someMeth1();
    abstract protected function someMeth2();

    public function someMeth3() {
        // Do common thing to both Order_WooExport and Order_WPExport
        // using someMeth1(), someMeth2()...
    }
}
```

Then :

```
class Order_WooExport extends Order_Export
{
    protected function someMeth1() {
        // Do something specific
    }

    protected function someMeth2() {
        // Do something specific
    }
}
```

Finally, the factory seems to be the right way to go too.